# Does HD 6450 graphics card work fine on Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, ati

Does HD 6450 work ok with Ubuntu 11.10? I have desktop computer and my screen is connected with DVI. I want to know should it work ok with Ubuntu and proprietary drivers. 
And my computer has an AMD APU Processor, which has GPU + CPU in one. But can i be sure it uses the HD 6450 card, not the integrated GPU from CPU.

Comment: Well since there's no funky Dual GPU stuff going on here I'd say yes it works.

Answer (score 2):

ATi have official Linux drivers for it so I imagine it works fine

Source: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

Answer (score 1):

All radeon HD cards "work" with Ubuntu in the sense that you can use them to display graphics using at least one driver (vesa would be the worst case scenario), but maybe you wanted to ask if 3d acceleration will be supported?

As for knowing which GPU is used, I would first visit the BIOS as there may well be some options in there that are relevant to this question. Second, you can run `lspci` and `lspci -v` from the command line to see what PCI(e) devices are seen by the operating system.
Finally, I would look at the X11 server log file (`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` generally) to see what devices the server found and initialized.

Comment: When i was using from live CD, i did lspci command. And it gave this: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc NI Caicos [AMD RADEON HD 6450]
01:00.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc NI Caicos HDMI Audio [AMD RADEON HD 6450]. So when i get install done, i just download drivers for it?

Comment: Yes, if you want 3d support, you will have to install the ATI proprietary driver.

Comment: Thanks, i will install Ubuntu now to my computer and i will install those drivers since i want 3D Support. :) And probably my question about APU CPU was stupid, since if my screen is connected to HD 6450, how i would get picture to screen if it would use the integrated GPU. =)

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the Biostar Radeon HD6450 pcie (DVI+VGA+HDMI) works fine with Ubuntu 12.04; u get OpenGL accel along with desktop effects (compiz) and tested with UrbanTerror to verify proper 3D gaming.Although I couldnt make the card works with an HDMI tv, DVI output is ok.